# SUM of values from different tables and put into another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have sales from 4 different table with different naming. Ex. HR sales, Customer sales etc.

I need the following like this.

```
            Type    Sales   
 ---------------------- 
  Table1    FCL        ?
  Table2    LCL        ?
  Table3    Import     ?
  Table4    Export     ?
           Overall      ?
```

I tried with following query,

```
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[Warehouse_Type] ([Overall Revenue])
 SELECT (SELECT SUM([Amount]) FROM [dbo].[Bond_Overall]) +
(SELECT SUM([Amount]) FROM [dbo].[Export_Overall])+
(SELECT SUM([TOTAL BILLING]) FROM [dbo].[FCL Test]) +
(SELECT SUM([Total Revenue Generated]) FROM [dbo].[LCL_overall])
```

Note: My query gives sum of value from different table, while I need sum to update individual values. Ex. in my query 1st select gives sum of 1st type and 2nd select gives sum of 2nd type and so on. I need to append to that another table named warehouse_type with its type.

Which gives overall revenue and its value but not other types.

Can anyone help me on this query to calculate and update sales of each type?

Comment: I don't see what your results have to do with your query.

Comment: What is the relation between those tables?

Comment: I have added what my query does.

Answer (score 3):

First make union of sales:

```
(SELECT 'Import' As Type, SUM([Amount]) FROM [dbo].[Bond_Overall])
Union All
(SELECT 'Export' As Type, SUM([Amount]) FROM [dbo].[Export_Overall])
Union All
(SELECT 'FCL' As Type, SUM([TOTAL BILLING]) FROM [dbo].[FCL Test])
Union All
(SELECT 'LCL' As Type, SUM([Total Revenue Generated]) FROM [dbo].[LCL_overall])
```

If you want to insert:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Warehouse_Type](Type, Sales) ([Overall Revenue])
Select From (
(SELECT 'Import', SUM([Amount]) FROM [dbo].[Bond_Overall])
Union All
(SELECT 'Export', SUM([Amount]) FROM [dbo].[Export_Overall])
Union All
(SELECT 'FCL', SUM([TOTAL BILLING]) FROM [dbo].[FCL Test])
Union All
(SELECT 'LCL', SUM([Total Revenue Generated]) FROM [dbo].[LCL_overall])) As D
```

Maybe subselect is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT 'FCL' [Type], SUM(Col) Sales
  FROM Table1
  UNION
  SELECT 'LCL', SUM(Col)
  FROM Table2
  UNION
  SELECT 'Import', SUM(Col)
  FROM Table3
  UNION
  SELECT 'Export', SUM(Col)
  FROM Table4
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
UNION
SELECT 'Overall', SUM(Sales)
FROM CTE;
```

If you want to insert the values to your table then

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Warehouse_Type] ([Overall Revenue])
SELECT Sales
FROM CTE
UNION
SELECT SUM(Salse)
FROM CTE;
```

---

<sub>I don't know what's the needs for `Type` if you won't insert it.</sub>